# Как сделать чтобы бот отправлял сообщение двум людям telebot

Tags: python, telebot

Есть такой код

```
bot.send_message(admin, f'Привет эчпочмак', parse_mode = "Markdown", reply_markup = inline_keyboard)
```

Он отправляет сообщение админу `admin = 123456789 # ID Админа`
но так же у меня есть саппорт `support = 987654321 # ID Саппорта`
Как сделать чтобы бот отправлял сообщение обоим, а не только админу

Comment: Можно продублировать функцию ```send_message```, только во второй раз ```admin``` заменить на ```support```

Answer (score 0):

```
def send(*id):
  for i in range(len(id)):
   bot.send_message(id[i], f'Привет эчпочмак', parse_mode = "Markdown", reply_markup = inline_keyboard)
```

Comment: и пишем: send(123456789,987654321,0000000,555555) и думаю смысл понятен

Comment: проще говоря: функция принимает кортеж и циклом обрабатывает каждый элемент, который является id, и отправляет сообщение